# Como compartilhar um pdf que esta numa webview em Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Tenho uma webview e nela chamo um endereço que se acessado por um navegador força um download de um PDF, no app que criei carreguei o PDF numa webview, porém gostaria de também dar a opção do usuario de compartilhar este PDF por e-mail, enviar ao IcloudDrive, mandar para o Ibook`s etc.

```
func asyncTask(parametros: String, id: String) {

        DispatchQueue.global(qos: DispatchQoS.userInitiated.qosClass).async {

            DispatchQueue.main.async 
                let boletoURL = URL(string: "http://www.meusite/01_2017.pdf")
                print(boletoURL!)
                let boletoURLRequest = URLRequest(url: boletoURL!)
                self.webView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
                self.webView.loadRequest(boletoURLRequest)
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você deve usar a framework da apple específica pra compor mensagens chamada MessageUI. Para você anexar um arquivo em email voce precisa ler os dados do seu pdf e usar o método addAttachmentData para anexá-los ao email. Caso o seu arquivo esteja online você precisa baixar de forma assíncrona usando URLSession dataTaskWithURL. Se quiser salvar o arquivo no disco antes de anexar ao email use downloadTaskWithURL:

```
import MessageUI
class ViewController: UIViewController, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!
    @IBAction func compose(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
            let mailComposer = MFMailComposeViewController()
            mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self
            mailComposer.setToRecipients(["email@address.com"])
            mailComposer.setSubject("Assunto !!!")
            mailComposer.setMessageBody("Texto da mensagem", isHTML: false) // texto padrao ou codigo html
            // para mandar um arquivo que esta online voce precisa baixar ele antes:
            let text = "Se quiser mandar um arquivo de texto por exemplo"
            mailComposer.addAttachmentData(Data(text.utf8), mimeType: "text/plain", fileName: "arquivo.txt")
            // voce pode enviar mais de um arquivo attached se necessario.
            // caso voce precise baixar o arquivo antes eu recomendo URL Session dataTaskWithURL
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string:"https://www.domain.com/arquivo.pdf")!) { data, response, error in
                guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                    print(error ?? "nil")
                    UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
                    self.button.isEnabled = true
                    return
                }
                print("bytes:", data.count)
                mailComposer.addAttachmentData(data, mimeType: "application/pdf", fileName: "arquivo.pdf")
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.present(mailComposer, animated: true)
                }           
            }.resume()
            button.isEnabled = false
            UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
            print("download started !!! ao final do download a janela de email sera apresentada !!!")
        }
    }
    func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {
        controller.dismiss(animated: true) { 
            switch result {
                case .cancelled: print("cancelled")
                case .saved:     print("saved")
                case .sent:
                    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Mail Composer", message: "Mail was successfully sent", preferredStyle: .alert)
                    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Done", style: .default, handler: nil))
                    self.present(alert, animated: true)
                case .failed:    print("failed")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Adicionei um botão na webview conectei ele com essa func que vc criou mas não acontece nada. retornou este log:  2017-03-31 13:02:55.007482-0300 Unip[1449:256368] [MC] Filtering mail sheet accounts for bundle ID: br.com.julio.Unip, source account management: 1
2017-03-31 13:02:55.008939-0300 Unip[1449:256368] [MC] Result: NO

Comment: App transport security info plist exception domain list

Comment: retornou isso agora: [MC] Invalidating cache

Comment: Julio didicil ajudar se voce não perguntar direito. acredito que o seu problema seja apenas segurança do App. se quiser deixar baixar arquivo de qualquer lugar tem que habilitar allow arbitrary downloads o que não tem nada haver com a sua pergunta em questão. Se voce google isso voce vai achar um monte de resultados mostrando como alterar a sua info.plist. A finalidade do site não é essa. Se eu escrever o seu código inteiro voce não vai aprender nada e vai voltar aqui pra pedir pra consertar qualquer erro que der no seu codigo

Comment: Leo Dabus, o allow arbitrary esta habilitado. Eu não estou entendendo sua colocação, estou pesquisando soluções para isso há dias e o maximo que consegui foi compartilhar o link, ai decidi perguntar, se alguém vai querer ajudar ai já é outra historia, se aparecer alguém que colocar realmente a solução com certeza irei dar o credito, só que vc quer credito sem resolver a pergunta????, eu realmente sou novo nisso e estou aqui aprendendo, quem quiser me ensinar agradeço de coração, quem não quiser nem precisa postar, basta guardar seu conhecimento pra vc mesmo.

Comment: Se o seu codigo tivesse realmente funcionado eu com certeza lhe falaria

Comment: kkkkk Quer que eu poste um zip do projeto ???

Comment: Se poder agradeço, de verdade minha intenção aqui não é discutir nem menosprezar ninguém, estou aqui para aprender

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8rsrs2ed3qedrfi/Mail%20Composer.zip?dl=1

Comment: Eu tenho que testar pelo celular certo??, testei seu projeto pelo emulador e não acontecia nada, mas partindo do princípio que ele vai baixar o PDF poderia estar faltando alguma permissão no MAC que desconheço, aí resolvi instalar no celular e funcionou. Obrigado

Comment: Não deve ter funcionado no emulador por que voce precisa configurar uma conta de email. de nada

Answer (score 0):

Olá, para este caso use o `UIActivityViewController`:

```
if  let shareURL = URL(string: "http://www.meusite/01_2017.pdf") {

    var shareItems = [Any]()
    shareItems.append("Compartilhar em...")
    shareItems.append(shareURL)

    let avController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: shareItems, applicationActivities: nil)
    avController.excludedActivityTypes : [UIActivityType] = [
        .postToWeibo, 
        .message,
        .mail,
        .print,
        .copyToPasteboard,
        .assignToContact,
        .saveToCameraRoll,
        .addToReadingList,
        .postToFlickr,
        .postToVimeo,
        .postToTencentWeibo,
        .airDrop
    ] // caso queira excluir alguma opção

    self.present(avController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Felipe, obrigado pelo comentario, mas não funcionou apenas compartilhou o link

Comment: @JulioFigueiredo tente ao invés de enviar uma `URL`, enviar o `Data`. Algo tipo: `let data = Data(contentsOfURL: shareURL)`. Aí você adiciona o resultado em: `shareItems.append(data)`. Abs!